# Google Sheets conditional formatting adapt to value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm currently working on a Google Sheet which tracks hourly performance, the layout is basic which is hours against units completed. The conditional format I already have in place works for a time base of one hour and is a generic GAR system. When we have heads on break the hour goes down to 0.5 which obviously throws the conditional formatting as the performance target is different. Is there a way to have a conditional formatting that can adapt depending on the time input?

Comment: can you provide an example? You can set a formula for conditional formatting that will change the performance target